A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client
I have a web API application that executes updates to a NVARCHAR(MAX) column and immediately after reads the result from the database. This usually works fine, but under high load it often fails with both "A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client" as well as simply returning garbage.
It is known that using "READ UNCOMMITTED" or using "NOLOCK" hints can cause this - but we are doing neither.
Every operation runs in SNAPSHOT isolation mode and consists of a SELECT with (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK), followed by a UPDATE followed by a SELECT with no hints - all on the same table and record. In between these calls there are many SQL writes to internal logging tables, but those never fails.
What we experience is that the second SELECT either fails with "A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client" - or that it returns data which is either truncated or include additional content.
The test operation that is able to reproduce this scenario consistently updates the same NVARCHAR(MAX) column with alternating large and small values - some requests set it to a short string and some request set it to a long string (thousands of characters). When many of these operations are run concurrently, we start seeing the error.
Updating with the same value all the time does not trigger the problem. So apparently, what happens is that data from different requests gets mixed up - writing in one transaction influences reading in another transaction ... which should not be possible.
Any ideas? Are NVARCHAR(MAX) "LOB" columns not protected by SQL server in this scenario?
The application runs on ASP.NET using SQL Server 2022 as a database.

Updlock and Holdlock seems take no effect in Snapshot isolation, from adonet doc about SQLServer: No locks are acquired on the underlying data rows or data pages in a snapshot transaction. Snapshot level seems more suitable for read-only access.

So, you're selecting to lock rows, then running an update, then running another select. What's wrong with a single statement: UPDATE ... OUTPUT?

Nothing wrong with UPDATE ... OUTPUT - just not done here.

"Updlock and Holdlock take no effect in Snapshot isolation" - it does make a difference. It ensures we read the newest value, not the value it had when the transaction started, if another transaction modified it after the current transaction started.

I understand, just suggesting - given the problem you're experiencing - you might consider it. Even in the absence of this problem, one table access is better than three.

I'm kinda curious, why are you modifying same LOB value concurrently? Are you working on one big large json document? Or is this some kind of collaborative book writing exercise

"why are you modifying same LOB value concurrently?". Well, I don't know :-) We provide the web API and one of our customers are running a large integration with it. Can't really say more. We have asked them to avoid concurrent updates to the same record - but they ignored the advice. We can add more internal locking to avoid the issue - but for now, I want to know what happens.

i'm guessing you're not using whatever isolation you say you use, set isolation explicitely and then post exact sql you're running so it's possible to replicate

"then post exact sql you're running so it's possible to replicate". Agreed, that would be nice, but there is a ton of other stuff going on in parallel. SQL Profiler says we use Snapshot on all SQL requests. It is very likely that this issue does not happen all on its own. But it could be that someone saw the issue and said "Ha! I've seen that before ...".

Nope.  Never seen that before.  Make sure you're on the latest CU and try to create a repro.  And consider opening a support case.

We tried to create a standalone example, but was unable to reproduce the issue outside the API implementation - so something else is certainly at play here, although it is impossible to say what.
But we did find a fix. As stated before, the sequence is:

START TRANSACTION -- using snapshot isolation
SELECT FROM X -- without locks
SELECT FROM X WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) -- same X but with locks
UPDATE X -- write large blob of text into VARCHAR(max)
SELECT FROM X -- without locks
COMMIT

For unknown reasons, it would fail at (5) every now and then. Either with a "A read operation on a large object failed while sending data to the client" - or by truncating or adding random characters to the returned string.
We then changed the last SELECT to be a SELECT with locks:

START TRANSACTION -- using snapshot isolation
SELECT FROM X -- without locks
SELECT FROM X WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) -- same X but with locks
UPDATE X -- write large blob of text into VARCHAR(max)
SELECT FROM X WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) -- with locks
COMMIT

Now, step (5) never fails.

This answer is as unclear as the question - there's no client code or any indication why two identical SELECTs are made instead of just one. The phrase unable to reproduce the issue outside the API suggests the client code is doing something it shouldn't do. It's unclear whether the sequence of steps is performed by the client, database, in the same connection or multiple ones. If you want to use pessimistic concurrency, don't use SNAPSHOT at all. The combination of locks essentially tries to make this a SERIALIZABLE transaction.
